# Cannot get my app to playback a YouTube video, what do I need to change? This is on an android 4.0.3 device...see logcat output below

Tags: android-youtube-api

11-28 15:08:02.899    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
11-28 15:08:02.899    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
11-28 15:08:02.899    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
11-28 15:08:02.899    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
11-28 15:08:02.899    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at java.util.Calendar.getHwFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.java:807)
11-28 15:08:02.899    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at java.util.Calendar.(Calendar.java:745)
11-28 15:08:02.899    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at java.util.GregorianCalendar.(GregorianCalendar.java:338)
11-28 15:08:02.899    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at java.util.GregorianCalendar.(GregorianCalendar.java:325)
11-28 15:08:02.899    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.ASN1Time.getDecodedObject(ASN1Time.java:44)
11-28 15:08:02.899    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.ASN1UTCTime.decode(ASN1UTCTime.java:82)
11-28 15:08:02.899    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.ASN1Choice.decode(ASN1Choice.java:308)
11-28 15:08:02.899    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.BerInputStream.readSequence(BerInputStream.java:554)
11-28 15:08:02.899    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.DerInputStream.readSequence(DerInputStream.java:105)
11-28 15:08:02.899    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.ASN1Sequence.decode(ASN1Sequence.java:40)
11-28 15:08:02.899    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.BerInputStream.readSequence(BerInputStream.java:554)
11-28 15:08:02.899    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.DerInputStream.readSequence(DerInputStream.java:105)
11-28 15:08:02.899    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.ASN1Sequence.decode(ASN1Sequence.java:40)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.BerInputStream.readSequence(BerInputStream.java:554)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.DerInputStream.readSequence(DerInputStream.java:105)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.ASN1Sequence.decode(ASN1Sequence.java:40)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.ASN1Type.decode(ASN1Type.java:91)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.security.provider.cert.X509CertImpl.(X509CertImpl.java:102)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.security.provider.cert.X509CertFactoryImpl.getCertificate(X509CertFactoryImpl.java:656)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.security.provider.cert.X509CertFactoryImpl.engineGenerateCertificate(X509CertFactoryImpl.java:109)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:195)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeApiServiceUtil.a(Unknown Source)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeApiServiceUtil.isYouTubeApiServiceAvailable(Unknown Source)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.e(Unknown Source)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a(Unknown Source)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity$a.a(Unknown Source)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.initialize(Unknown Source)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at com.example.alan.youtubeplayer.YouTubeActivity.onCreate(YouTubeActivity.java:28)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
11-28 15:08:02.909    5113-5113/com.example.alan.youtubeplayer W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

The app simply needed to be updated. The YouTube API needs an app version on the device higher than 4.2.16, mine was older than this so an update of the app sorted the problem.